# Unwanted horizontal scrollbar appears at bottom of browser (IE7)

Tags: css

Take a look at the following sites:

www.crandic.com
www.midwestsites.com

In IE7, an unwanted, horizontal scrollbar appears at the bottom of the browser for both sites. In FireFox 3.5.7, the scrollbar does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a CSS rule to hide any x-axis content overflow:

```
body {
 overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by this line:

```
font: italic bold 100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

for `.headertext` in INT_CRANDIC_CSS.css

I have **no idea** why!

Comment: Notably, the horizontal scrollbar is not a problem in either IE8 or Firefox.

Comment: Thanks to Sam and pygorex1. I added overflow: hidden; to the .headertext class and the unwanted horizonal scrollbar disappeared in both sites! Your responses are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a site and this CSS solved it for me:

```
html
{
    overflow: auto;
}
```